# Converting pseudo to mips

Tags: mips

I need help converting this pseudo code to mips. We are supposed to recursively reverse an array of integers.

```
/* Function to reverse arr[] from start to end*/
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
int temp;
if (start>= end)
 return;
reverseArray(arr, start+1, end-1);
temp = arr[start];
arr[start] = arr[end];
arr[end] = temp;
}

/* Utility that prints out an array on a line */
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
  printf(”%d ”, arr[i]);
printf(”\n”);
}

/* Driver function to test above functions */
int main()
{
int arr[] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
printf(”Original array is :  ”);
printArray(arr, 6);
reverseArray(arr, 0, 5);
printf(”Reversed array is :  ”);
printArray(arr, 6);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What _specifically_ is the problem?

Comment: I need help converting code into pseudo code. That’s my question. Like an example or something to help me do my homework

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the array using the stack push and pop concept:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqdj5.png)

MIPS CODE THAT PERFORMS PUSH AND POP:

```
.data

space: .asciiz " "

newline: .asciiz "\n"

array:   .word 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19
         .word 21, 22, 25, 27, 29, 33, 33, 35, 37, 39
         .word 41, 44, 45, 47, 49, 52, 53, 55, 57, 59
length:  .word 30
    
.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:

#loop to read items from array and push to stack

la $t0 array #array's starting address
li $t1 0     #loop index, i=0
lw $t2 length  #length


pushLoop:
lw $t4 ($t0)   #get array[i]
# printing array
addi $a0,$t4,0
li $v0,1
syscall
# printing space
li $v0, 4
la $a0, space   
syscall

subu $sp $sp 4
sw $t4 ($sp)

addi $t1 $t1 1 #i = i+1
add $t0 $t0 4 #update array address

blt $t1 $t2 pushLoop

#loop to pop items from stack and write into array
la $t0 array  #array's starting index
li $t1 0      #loop index i=0

lw $t2 length

popLoop:
lw $t4 ($sp)
addu $sp $sp 4

sw $t4 ($t0)     #set array [i]

add $t1 $t1 1   #i=i+1
add $t0 $t0 4   #update array address

blt $t1 $t2 popLoop #if i<length continue

#giving space of a line
li $v0,4
la $a0, newline
syscall

la $t0 array  #array's starting index
li $t1 0      #loop index i=0
lw $t2 length

traverseArray:
lw $t4 ($t0)   #get array[i]
# printing array
addi $a0,$t4,0
li $v0,1
syscall
# 
#printing space
li $v0, 4
la $a0, space   
syscall

addi $t1 $t1 1 #i = i+1
add $t0 $t0 4 #update array address

blt $t1 $t2 traverseArray

li $v0 10
syscall
.end main
```